# jq - find a value of a non-unique key when another value is known

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, jq

I am struggling to construct a proper filter for jq to find the value of a specific key when the value of another key is known.

Here is the json file:

```
[
    {
        "Header": {
            "Tenant": "TenantX",
            "Rcode": 200
        },
        "Body": {
            "values": [
                {
                    "id": "aaaa0001-0a0a-0b0b-0a95-6625bef115e5",
                    "name": "Attribute1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "aaaa0001-0a0a-0b0b-9926-f5dc47d312dd",
                    "name": "Attribute2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "aaaa0001-0a0a-0b0b-aea9-6b39641a0695",
                    "name": "Attribute3"
                },
                {
                    "id": "aaaa0001-0a0a-0b0b-a62b-5b26838eeca7",
                    "name": "Attribute4"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

My goal - for any given value of the "name" key, find the value of the "id" key in the same {} block. Or to have as an example as pseudocode/task:

```
When Header.Tenant ==="TenantX" and Body.values[].name =="Attribute1" 
then
display the value of "id"  
in the same block where "Attribute1" is
```

Values of the `"id"` and `"name"` are unique, but the position of the combination of name/id in the `Body.values[]` array can be anywhere. In other words, for one tenant `Attribute1` can be in the first element of the array, and for another tenant - in 10th. Also, some tenants can have certain `name/id` in the array and others do not.

I guess if I can find the unique position `n` for the given attribute within the array -  `Body.values[n].name`, then `Body.values[n].id` should give me the answer, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the objects in the `values` array with

```
.[].Body.values[]
```

and then select the `id` of the objects where `name` matches your string:

```
.[].Body.values[] | select(.name == "Attribute1").id
```